# Selenium: Click and Hold the element and then Slide it

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

In my application I have a scenario where I need to slide an element in list view to add new entry to the item. I have to automate it using Selenium and C#. Application is developed using Ionic and Angular Frameworks.

In Selenium there is an option to `ClickAndHold` and `MoveByOffset` methods but none of these seems to be working. At the same time no errors are displayed. Please help.

Code I have tried so far is as below.

`Actions dragger = new Actions(driver);`

`elementToSlide = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ion-item-slide[1]"));`

`dragger.ClickAndHold(elementToSlide).MoveByOffset(-47,0).Build().Perform();`

Images are attached for reference. The first element in the list view slides.

[image: Before performing slide]

[image: After performing slide]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, actually I figured out in ionic framework we should not use ion-item-sliding element for sliding, but the next child which is ion-item. I did by using the following code.

`var slidableItm = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ion-item-sliding/ion-item");`

`Actions dragger = new Actions(driver);`

`dragger.ClickAndHold(slidableItm))).MoveByOffset(-47, 0).Build().Perform();`

Then after sliding we need to click on some element's coordinates to complete and release the slide. It can be achieved by following code.

`var clickableItm = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/ion-item-sliding/ion-item/div[1]/div/ion-label/div/p[1]"));`

`ILocatable c = (ILocatable)clickableItm;`

`RemoteWebDriver rd = (RemoteWebDriver)driver;`

`rd.Mouse.Click(c.Coordinates);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the drag and drop command could solve your problem,try like this

```
IWebElement elementToSlide = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ion-item-slide[1]"))
Actions dragger = new Actions(driver);
dragger.DragAndDropToOffset(elementToSlide, -47, 0).Build().Perform();
```

Comment: No this is not working either. Nothing is happening in the screen and no error is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I wrote the code like this and it worked for me:

```
                Actions action = new Actions(driver);
                action.clickAndHold(elementToSlide);
                action.moveToElement(NextplaceElement).release();
                action.build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Actions a = new Actions(driver);
```

a.clickAndHold(e2).pause(2000).moveToElement(e1).release().build().perform();